# How to filter or omit data by vector value?

Tags: r

Hi Stackoverflow comunity. I research electricity price dynamics and have a question regarding filtering or omiting values from a large data.frame.

My data.frame looks like this and originally has 15 variables:

```
 time_stamp price; renw_elec; wday;
 01.01.2014; 12.5;  25,562.25;  3;
 02.01.2014; 14.5;  23,896.56;  4;
 03.01.2014; 17.6;  26,634.87;  5;
 04.01.2014; 12.9;  30,214,56;  6;
 05.01.2014; 10.5;  21,256.56;  0;
 06.01.2014; 20.4;  28,985.78;  1;
 07.01.2014; 22.7;  32,578.98;  2;
```

What I was trying to do is to filter the data.frame depending on values in the variable wday. For instance, omitting all rows in the data.frame for values 0 and 1 in the variable wday, to make it look like this:

```
 time_stamp price; renw_elec; wday;
 01.01.2014; 12.5;  25,562.25;  3;
 02.01.2014; 14.5;  23,896.56;  4;
 03.01.2014; 17.6;  26,634.87;  5;
 04.01.2014; 12.9;  30,214,56;  6;
 07.01.2014; 22.7;  32,578.98;  2;
```

I did try to do it with `df$wday[is.na(df$wday)]<-0`, as described on cran, but it did not work at all. What do i do wrong, or how to solve such a problem the best way?
Thank you for your help in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you can also do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(wday > 1)

  time_stamp price renw_elec wday
1 01.01.2014  12.5  25562.25    3
2 02.01.2014  14.5  23896.56    4
3 03.01.2014  17.6  26634.87    5
4 04.01.2014  12.9  30214.56    6
5 07.01.2014  22.7  32578.98    2
```

Answer (score 1):

It is basic filtering on a data.frame:

```
df[df$wday!=0 & df$wday!=1,]
```

or

```
df[df$wday>1,]
```

or

```
vec = c(0,1)
df[!(df$wday %in% vec),]
```

Comment: I think that last option might need to be wrapped with `all` maybe?

Comment: `df$wday %in% vec` returns the boolean vector indicating if there is a 0 or 1 on each line. Why should it be wrapped with `all` since it returns a single boolean?